# Excel Pivot Tables - Calculated Field of a Calculated Field

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I'm using Excel 2010.

I have a data set of widgets made by person by period. I created a calculated field that shows each person's widgets made as a percentage of the total for each period.

I would like to now show the change in that "percent of total" from period to period. That is to say, I want to see how each person's percentage of the total widgets made has change from the previous period. It's a calculation on a calculation and perhaps it's just wishful thinking that Excel supports this, but it would be great if it did.

Can anyone confirm if this is possible and if so, how would I approach it? I've been looking into creating a custom Calculated Field, but I don't see how to do percent to total or difference from in those (perhaps because it would be redundant?)

Comment: Under **Field Configuration**, go to **Show valules as** and then select **% Difference From**. Under **Base field** select your period field, and under **Base element** select **(previous)**.

Comment: The field in question is already configured as % of Column Total. If I change it to what you suggest, what I would get would be the difference in widgets that person made in that period vs what they made in the previous period. I don't want the difference in widgets made, I want the difference in the % of Column Total. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You can do a double pivot then -  define a Dynamic Named Range that holds your current pivot and make a second pivot table with this Named Range as its data source. I can do an answer showing how to do this if you need help.